# Python plugin - WordBlitz - can't get it to work for Czech language

Tags: python

I am trying to make [this plugin](https://github.com/taixhi/wordblitz) work for Czech. I have found a list of Czech words but when I input the letters of the game, it doesn't find any words within those letters. Perhaps the encoding is wrong?
I changed this (from the generator.py file):

```
f = open('czech3.txt', 'r')
```

into this:

```
f = open('czech3.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

but to no avail.

Comment: Try e. g. "print(f.read(1000))" to check how the decoded file looks like.

Comment: Omg it works now. I changed the source to capital letters. Sadly it found only a couple of words but that probably means just a wrong source file?